# elasticsearch match phrase_prefix and others

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

Hi i have a problem with elasticsearch, 
i have some result like

> - modul'ion
> - test lithium file

when a do a query if i type 'mod' i does not find the result, i add the type:"phrase_prefix" to my query and now i find the result

> modul'ion

but now when i type lithium a does not find the result

> test lithium file

my request

```
    $query ['match'] ['_all'] ["query"] = strtolower ( $keyword );
    $query ['match'] ['_all'] ["type"] = "phrase_prefix";
    $query ['match'] ['_all'] ["analyzer"] = "synonym";
```

also i use a synonym analyzer who contains "lithium =>Rechargeable Lithium"
my problem is if a does not use the analyzer or i remove

> $query ['match'] ['_all'] ["type"] = "phrase_prefix";

i find result but the problem with 'mod' is back 
 so i would like to get result in both situation can you help me ?

i set the analyzer with this query

```
 {"analysis" : {
    "analyzer" : {
        "synonym" : {
            "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
            "filter" : ["synonym"]
        }
    },
"filter" : {
            "synonym" : {
                "type" : "synonym",
                "synonyms_path" : "synonym.txt",
                "ignore_case" : true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is analyzed this text (give the analyzer set in mappings)? What do you mean by "if a remove the phrase_prefix type"?

Comment: Yes. What kind of analyzer is configured at index time (in the mappings)?

Comment: It is tough to give an answer without knowing how the document is analyzed at index time . FWIW you would need the synonyms to be lowercase too try  `"filter" : ["synonym","lowercase"] ` for the `synonym` analyzer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I don't see any issues with your mappings, they work just fine in backend. Your issue is that you're querying `_all` field, which needs to be configured seperately. If you're not specifying that, it will have default parameters, which can be seen [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html). In order to change that, I've used these settings and mappings :

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "char_filter": ["my_mapping"],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_synonym"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "ignore_case": true,
          "synonyms": [
            "rechargeable lithium => lithium"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_mapping": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "'=>"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": true,
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

These setting will break your tokens at whitespaces, remove quotes from tokens and lowercase them, so that:

- `modul'ion` would be indexed as `modulion` and whenever user types any of these phrases - he will find it.
- `rechargeable lithium` is replaced by `lithium` as a synonym.
- Due to `lowercase` filter, so your searches are case insensitive.

Using these mappings I've added your data into index with:

```
PUT /test/test/1
{
  "text": "modul'ion"
}

PUT /test/test/2
{
  "text": "test lithium file"
}
```

So now running this query:

```
POST /test/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": {
        "query": "rechargeable lithium",
        "type": "phrase_prefix"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Returns me this document:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.15342641,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.15342641,
        "_source": {
          "text": "test lithium file"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Both of following queries:

```
POST /test/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": {
        "query": "mod",
        "type": "phrase_prefix"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /test/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": {
        "query": "modulion",
        "type": "phrase_prefix"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Returns this:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.30685282,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.30685282,
        "_source": {
          "text": "modul'ion"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is just RAW JSON queries, but I guess you'll be able to deal with these in PHP just fine.

Comment: The `"query": "mod","type": "phrase_prefix"` query returns nothing for me. Would there be a reason why?

Comment: @Jared could you open a new question with more details and link this answer as a reference?

Comment: I see analysis may play a big role into my question I have [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777132/cross-field-search-with-multiple-complete-and-incomplete-phrases-in-each-field).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the query type but the synonyms. The synonym filter is usually use to replace a term by another, not a term by a whole phrase because the phrase won't be tokenized afterwards.

You must know that analysis is used twice: once when indexing and another time when searching. Let's suppose your documents where analyzed with the standard analyzer (the default one):

- Input "modul'ion" → 1 Indexed Term: "modul'ion"
- Input "test lithium file" → 3 Indexed Terms: "test","lithium","file"

If you're searching with the standard analyze as well (no synonyms) with phrase_prefix:

- Input "mod" → 1 Search Term Prefix "mod" found in #1
- Input "lithium" → 1 Search Term Prefix "lithium"  found in #2
- Input "test lithium" → 2 Search Term Prefix "test","lithium" found in #2

If you're searching with your custom analyzer (synonyms)

- Input "mod" → 1 Search Term Prefix "mod" found in #1
- Input "lithium" → 1 Search Term Prefix "Rechargeable Lithium" not found
- Input "test lithium" → 2 Search Term Prefix "test","Rechargeable Lithium" not found

You should also be cautious with casing if you're indexing in lowercase (the analysis chain at index time contains a lowercase filter), don't try to search in uppercase (the analysis chain at search time produces "Lithium" instead of "lithium").

If you're new to Elasticsearch I advise you to:

1. Start with the same analysis settings for indexing and searching. You already know how to configure an Analyzer, you only need to use the [Put Mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) to configuration indexing
2. Test the analysis chain with the [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html)

For example:

```
PUT the_index/_mapping/the_type 
{
  "properties": {
    "the_field": {
      "type": "string",
      "analyze": "the_analyzer"
    }
  }
}

GET the_index/_analyze?analyzer=synonym&text=modul'ion
GET the_index/_analyze?analyzer=synonym&text=test lithium
```